# installing opencv for python without success

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I followed [this](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2012/09/21/installing-opencv-for-python-on-mac-lion/) tutorial on how to install opencv on my mac (running 10.10.3). I also tried all of the suggestions listed in the stackoverflow post mentioned in the article.

When I run the line `import cv` the console returns:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named cv

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to get opencv working?

Comment: can you try import '/<path>/cv' , <path> must be in python folder somewhere or where you installed it

Comment: I tried that and didn't have any luck

Comment: can you try the install procedures from this : http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/12/14/face-detection-with-osx-and-python/

Comment: I second @Suddev's suggestion. In my experience `homebrew` does a much better and seamless job in these kind of situations.

Comment: I just did and got the same results... hmmm  I appreciate the help and suggestions.